# Is there a way to extract the css and javascript files used on a website, with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, webkit, service-worker

I'm building kind of a web browser and I'm using a `WKWebView`.
Now, I wish service workers were supported by `WebKit` but unfortunately, that's not the case. So I'd like to build a system that's closed to service workers.

The main thing is : I want previously visited web pages to be displayed in offline mode.

So my main idea would be to extract and store the `html`, `css` and `js` files from the web pages.

The problem is that I have no idea if this is possible or not and I really don't know how I could do what I want to do if it isn't possible.

Comment: You might be able to catch everything with `NSURLProtocol`, but it'll take some work. More on that here: http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/

Comment: Actually, it looks like there's even a tutorial on `NSURLProtocol` that will help you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial